# Getting expection on line "WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, apache-commons-io, webdrivermanager-java

I am facing the below issue
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'** on line "WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

I am using the latest WebDriverManager version i.e 5.3.1 and the latest commons.io version i.e 2.11.0

Comment: Q: are you including Apache Commons (including, but not limited to, commons.io) in your classpath?  If you're using Maven (or equivalent) for your build, then it should automatically identify, download and include library dependencies for you.  Otherwise, you'll need to add the dependencies yourself, manually.

Comment: No, I haven't added that in the .classpath file. Do I have to?
I have already added below code in the pom.xml

<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverManager 5.3.1 depends transitively on commons-io 2.6. You can try to force that version in your pom.

Comment: I tried with commons-io 2.6, but it's throwing the same error

Comment: Even though I am getting same issue if I don't add commons.io dependency in my pom.xml